# Save Bitmap image in a location in C#

Tags: c#

I have this function to store the bmp image in a desired location as shown below
My question is, how do I save the image in C:\temp folder by default, instead of opening the filedialog box?

I want to specify sd.fileName=picname+".bmp" and store it in c:\temp by default.

I tried to specify

Thanks for your help in advance.

I tried to

```
public static bool SaveDIBAs( string picname, IntPtr bminfo, IntPtr pixdat )
{
        SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();

        sd.FileName = picname;
        sd.Title = "Save bitmap as...";
        sd.Filter = "Bitmap file (*.bmp)|*.bmp|TIFF file (*.tif)|*.tif|JPEG file (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG file (*.png)|*.png|GIF file (*.gif)|*.gif|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        sd.FilterIndex = 1;
        if( sd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK )
            return false;

        Guid clsid;
        if( ! GetCodecClsid( sd.FileName, out clsid ) )
            {
            MessageBox.Show( "Unknown picture format for extension " + Path.GetExtension( sd.FileName ),
                            "Image Codec", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information );
            return false;
            }

        IntPtr img = IntPtr.Zero;
        int st = GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib( bminfo, pixdat, ref img );
        if( (st != 0) || (img == IntPtr.Zero) )
            return false;

        st = GdipSaveImageToFile( img, sd.FileName, ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero );
        GdipDisposeImage( img );
        return st == 0;
        }
```

Comment: When pasting code make sure that you've converted tabs to spaces. Tabs play havoc with the markdown -> HTML process. The editor sees tabs as lots of spaces, but the HTML sees it as one, so the code doesn't get rendered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you do not want to use a SaveFileDialog any at all.
Then I suggest you not to ;) . You are utilising SaveFileDialog to retrieve the path of the file which is SaveFileDialog.FileName in the line

```
st = GdipSaveImageToFile( img, sd.FileName, ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero );
```

Instead of sd.FileName, put the value you want; i.e, @"c:\temp\" + picname + ".bmp"

Remove anything that is related to SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`InitialDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) of the `SaveFileDialog` to "C:\temp":

```
sd.FilterIndex = 1;
sd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\temp";  // <--- Add this line
if( sd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK )
    return false;
```